# Django How to Add Custom Location Field?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my profile model I want to hold `country` or `city, country` values in custom location field. Also `country` value must be provided. So I made a `LocationField` which implements MultiValueField. I'm not advanced at Django, so how can I make only `country` required? Also I'm not sure this code is totally right.

P.S: I can make city and country fields in Profile but holding in them in one field seems more neat.

### models.py

```
from cities_light.models import City, Country

class Profile(models.Model):

    user                = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    first_name          = models.CharField(verbose_name='first name', max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default='baris') 
    last_name           = models.CharField(verbose_name='last name', max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default='baris')
    profile_photo       = models.ImageField(verbose_name='profile photo', ) #TODO add upload to
    about               = models.CharField(verbose_name='about', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    spoken_languages    = models.CharField(verbose_name='spoken languages', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    location            = LocationField()


class LocationField(MultiValueField):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        fields = (
            Country(),
            City()
        )
        super.__init__(fields=fields, require_all_fields=False, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If it's more "neat", then why does it require so much more work? If one value is required and one is not, then I can't see why they shouldn't be two separate fields.

Comment: "simple is better than complex" . Please use 2 fields and rid from complexity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want a `Location` model instead? You can add a field `type` that is either a city or country and add a `unique_together` field to limit profiles to one city and country each:

```py
COUNTRY = 0
CITY = 1

class Location(models.Model):

    LOCATION_TYPE_CHOICES = ((COUNTRY, 'country'), (CITY, 'city'))

    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', ..., related_name='locations')
    name = models.CharField(...)
    type = models.IntegerField(..., choices=LOCATION_TYPE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile', 'type')
```

Then you can access a profile's location like so:

```py
from . import models

profile = models.Profile.objects.get(id="<pofile-id>")

# either a location instance of type 'country' or None if none exist:
country = profile.locations.filter(type=models.COUNTRY).first()

# either a location instance of type 'city' or None if none exist:
city = profile.locations.filter(type=models.CITY).first()
```